# Aggregate SOQL Query Cannot Aggregate

Tags: apex, soql, aggregateresult

In my Product Object there is a list of ProductMatrices. I want to total sum of matrices field. So for that i used Aggregate soql. But its not showing aggregate result.

```
public List<AggregateResult> totalSummaryMatrix {get;set;}
```

---

```
totalSummaryMatrix = [Select Id,Product__c, SUM(Total_Sale__c)totalSalesSum, SUM(Order_Recieved__c)totalOrderSum, AVG(Sell_Through__c)average From Product_Matrix__c Where Product__c IN : prodIdsList Group By Id,Product__c];
System.debug('totalSummaryMatrix+++==='+totalSummaryMatrix);
```

please someone help me.

Comment: When you say *not showing*, how are you confirming it?

Comment: by using debug log

Comment: Did you get a `Product_Matrix__c` list depend on `prodIdsList`

Comment: Printing the list in debug will not give you the complete details. You should verify by printing the size of the list and/or iterating through the list to see the results. Also make sure that the running user has access to the records.

Comment: yes Product_Matrix__c list is depend on prodIdsList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not giving you a sum because your first grouping is on the `Id` of the `Product_Matrix__c`:

```
totalSummaryMatrix = [
    Select Id,Product__c, SUM(Total_Sale__c)totalSalesSum, SUM(Order_Recieved__c)totalOrderSum, AVG(Sell_Through__c)average 
    From Product_Matrix__c 
    Where Product__c IN : prodIdsList 
    Group By Id,Product__c
];
```

Each of your groups therefore has a size of one, since each record has a different Id, and the sum is coming back simply as the value of the field on that one object.

You should remove `GROUP BY Id` and only group by the field that defines the scope of each summary line item, which appears to be `Product__c`.